# Modal viewcontroller disappears unexpectedly

Tags: ios, objective-c

This question is one that I cant really give an example of as its very hard to capture on camera but it can be explained as this. I have a tabbed view app. Its a music player. Anyway, inside the tabs are tables and upon selecting a song from the table to play the app modals over (pushing or other transition types have the same effect here) to the now playing screen. Half the time that works fine, however the other half of the time it modals over for half a second then jumps back to the previous view controller for no reason.

**Can anyone explain what may cause this to happen, or what my next steps should be?**

This can also happen when selecting say an album and causing it to modal to songs in the album or whatever. It will unexpectedly jump back to the album view, likewise for playlists and so on, once again. This happens only half the time.

Comment: Please post some code so we know what you actually did. Sounds like you're using an instance variable for the VC that gets released. You need to keep a strong reference to it. But without any code that's really hard to tell

Comment: Its got nothing to do with variables because all infomation is displayed correctly on the view controller when it modals over. It is worth noting that whenever the app reverts, it always goes back to the viewcontroller represented in the tab bar that was last used. Ill post code when i have internet access on my laptop later today.

Comment: Oh wait. I think I have just discovered the source of the bug. I have a album cover flow view controller set to modal in upon rotation. It would appear that a slight rotation of the phone, say from straight up in the air to flat, is enougth to partially trigger the modal, not enougth to switch to the cover flow, but enougth to close all viewcontrollers down to the tab controller views, looks like I will need to rethink the modal trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, check the comments for more details.